# "Be the 1% that do not." vs "Be the 1% that does not." vs "Be the 1% who does not."

Tags: grammatical-number

I'm stuck on which is the correct grammar to use in my ad copy. The first sentence is "99% of patients have to wait." which is followed by (one of the following):

- "Be the 1% that do not."
- "Be the 1% that does not."
- "Be the 1% who does not."
- "Be the 1% who do not."

Comment: All of those feel like they need an indicator of belonging rather than being the definition. For example, "Be _part of_ the 1% that does not," or "Be _in_ the 1% that does not." I think that also makes using the singular/plural clearer.

Comment: 'Be one of the 1% who do not.' You are encouraging singular individuals to belong to a group.

Comment: My opinion is that "But you're special, because you're rich" has more zest.

Comment: 1% don't. be it.